# Json.NET public Activity properties not serialized

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net, xamarin.android

I was working on an enhancement in my Xamarin Android app to make working with Android's saved state easier. One part of the implementation for this needs to Json serialize the properties of current `Activity` class that have the custom `[SaveState]` attribute. All other properties are ignored. I've got this mechanism working using a POCO (and Json.NET as serializer). When defining a *public* property with the custom `[SaveState]` attribute, it serializes (only) that property as desired.

When I define a class that extends the (obviously) required `Activity` class, lets call it `ExampleActivity`, it doesn't serialize the *public* property anymore. So, the same setup that was working for the POCO isn't working anymore when extending the `Activity`.

In addition: it's not serializing anything of the `ExampleActivity` or of the inherited `Activity`'s properties. Even though many are *public*. Just an empty Json string object.

When I add the `[JsonProperty]` attribute to the *public* property it d̲o̲e̲s̲ though! So I believe it's not a matter that Json.NET can't serialize the property, it just won't. For some reason it's ignoring it and everything else.

I've tried some things, but I can't seem to figure out why it's ignoring the properties. I've added a `TraceWriter` to the serializer in the hopes to see something that might point me in the right direction, but it doesn't.

I've added a small stripped code snippet that reproduces the issue:

```
public static class Example
{
    public static void Run()
    {
        var exampleActivity = new ExampleActivity { PropertyA = "A value", PropertyB = "B value" };

        // Default serializer settings with a memory trace writer
        var serializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings { TraceWriter = new MemoryTraceWriter() };
        var serializedString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(exampleActivity, serializerSettings);

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(serializerSettings.TraceWriter);

        // NOTE: The serialized string only contains PropertyB
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"SerializedString: {serializedString}");
    }

    public class ExampleActivity : Activity
    {
        //[JsonProperty]
        public string PropertyA { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty]
        public string PropertyB { get; set; }
    }
}
```

When calling the static `Example.Run()` you'll see that even though the `ExampleActivity`'s `PropertyA` is a regular public property it's not serialized. Whereas the `PropertyB` which has the `[JsonProperty]` attribute i̲s̲ serialized.

For my solution I don't want to be adding the `[JsonProperty]` attribute to each property that also get's the custom `[SaveState]` attribute. That it's currently using Json (de)serializing behind the scenes to achieve the desired behavior shouldn't have influence on the usage of the `[SaveState]` behavior.

I hope I've been sufficiently complete in the describing of my issue. Does anybody know why the regular *public* properties of the class extending the `Activity` aren't serialized? And/or how to fix this?

Comment: One possibility is that `Activity` or some base class has `DataContract` or `[JsonObject(MemberSerialization = MemberSerialization.OptIn)]` set.  See [JsonObjectAttribute opt-in serialization](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonObjectAttributeOptIn.htm).

Comment: If the `Activity` class is somehow using opt-in serialization, you can force opt-out serialization using `OptOutContractResolver` from [Populating non-serializable object with Json.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30825847)

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. It does seem to serialize OptIn indeed! The `OptOutContractResolver` solves the issue. I did choose to implement my contract resolver in a different matter, also solving the issue, but this led me on the right track. Thanks!